# Python DataFrames to JSon

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I want to store my Python script output to the JSon format below :

```
 [{
   "ids": "1",
   "result1": ["1","2","3","4"],
   "result2": ["4","5","6","1"]
}, 
{
  "ids": "2",
  "result1": ["3","4"],
  "result2": ["4","5","6","1"]
}]
```

My code is as follows

```
for i in df.id.unique():
    ids = i
    results1 = someFunction(i)
    results2 = someFunction2(i)
    df_result_int = ["ids : %s" %ids , "results1 : %s" %results1, "results2 : %s" %results2]
    df_results.append(df_result_int)

jsonData = json.dumps(df_results)

with open('JSONData.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(jsonData, f)
```

someFunction() and someFunction2() return a list.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should not manually transform your lists to string, json.dumps does it for you. Use dictionaries instead. Here is an example:

```
df_results = []
results1 = [1,1]
results2 = [2,2]
df_result_int = {"ids" : 1, "results1" : results1, "results2" : results2}
df_results.append(df_result_int)

json.dumps(df_results)
```

This will result in:

```
[{"results2": [2, 2], "ids": 1, "results1": [1, 1]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for pandas dataframes that allows you to dump the dataframe directly to a json file. Here the link to the documentation:
[to_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)
You could use something like

```
df.reset_index().to_json(orient='records')
```

where df is the dataframe on which you have done some sort of manipulation before (for example the functions you wish to apply, etc.) and it depends on the info you want in the json file and how is arranged.

Comment: Thak you for your response, I tried to use it but the reset_index causes a problem.

Comment: You can just remove the `reset_index()` part and just have  `df.to_json(orient='records') `.  But probably the other answer will serve your case faster without too many modifications to the code you already have, since we don't know the data layout...